# How to install kubectl in ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubectl

After install kubectl in WSL, if I connect with my Azure cluster using following command

```
az account set --subscription <subscription ID>
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <RG name> --name <Cluster name>
kubectl get ns
```

It is not able to connect & showing following error.

```
localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port
```

Answer (score 4):

I face huge problem to install WSL & install kubectl into WSL. Using this following steps I have install both the component successfully in my system. Please find the following.

Step 1:-
Enable **Windows subsystem for linux** :- check this reference it will guide you to install WSL properly in your system.

https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10

Step 2:- Install kubectl into WSL. find the following reference link it will help you (https://rancher.com/learning-paths/how-to-manage-kubernetes-with-kubectl/)

I use the following command step by step. For my case kubectl already install in my windows PowerShell

- curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.21.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
- sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
- sudo apt-get update

Now your kubectl get install in your ubuntu terminal. we can execute the following command to test kubectl.

```
az account set --subscription <subscription ID>
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <RG name> --name <Cluster name>
```

Test your kubectl configuration to execute following command

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

if it's not showing your cluster details or it's showing following error

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port
```

Don't worry.. I did a trick, I locate my `c:\Users\<username>\.kube\config` file and copy it into my WSL `cp config ~/.kube/`

After that it's start working.